# jQuery UI maps and getScript() not working together

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-map

I wrote the following snippet:

```
$.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true", function() {
  $.getScript("/media/lib/jquery.ui.map.js", function() {
    $.getScript("/media/lib/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js",  function() {
      $.getScript("/media/lib/jquery.ui.map.overlays.js", function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'zoom', 14);
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('option', 'disableDefaultUI', true);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

For applying the .gmaps() function to my map_canvas asynchronously. If I load the exact same files (incl. path) via  tag, I don't have any issues. If I use the cascaded version above, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The issue seems to be, that gmap() is not defined. Why?

Does anyone see the issue with my code?

Pat

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, looking for solution now, but you can see a parser error on the console.

```
$.getScript( url ).done( function(script, textStatus, jqxhr) {
       console.log(script); //data returned
       console.log(textStatus); //success
       console.log(jqxhr.status); //200
    }).fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {
        console.error('Error when loading a JS: ', settings);
    });
```